# Add 30 years to date php

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-7

i want to add 30 years to a date in php. it's work fine in 20 years, but when replace 20 years with 30 years ,it's showing the default date. like this 1970-01-01. This is what i done .

```
$created_date = '2017-12-30 08:30:27'

$futureDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 year', strtotime($created_date)) );

echo $futureDate;
```

o/p :

```
1970-01-01
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Your code [is working for me](http://rextester.com/MVPKLN62374).  Can you post a reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: Even I don't see any issue https://ideone.com/2Xp7PS

Comment: You probably exceed the timestamp. A number of years from now the  timestamp will work no longer. We had the 2000 year issue, but now will be another issue when timestamp hits the max.

Comment: From manual **possible dates might end on 2038-01-19 03:14:07**. What date did you start with?

Comment: when i googled , it's showing like this --> "The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer)" ... ?

Comment: Andreas ,, 'What date did you start with' ? means ?

Comment: $created_date = '2017-12-30 08:30:27' this date is insert to database when a new user register , i need to add 30 years to that date for ' user membership' valid ?

Comment: If you actually start with a date in 2017 then there is no reason why your code does not work. Unless you have not copy paste but changed something when posting here.

Comment: FWIW, it seems insane to be planning 30 years ahead… Just store the registration date, and *iif* your app still exists in 30 years you can do the retroactive calculations based on that then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
<?php

$created_date = '2017-12-30 08:30:27';

$EndDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $created_date);
$EndDateTime->modify('+30 years');
echo $EndDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:- https://eval.in/928779

Answer (score 4):

In 32 bit there was a bug which can't handle dates after that year 2038.

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead which does work around this issue 2038.

For PHP 5.3+

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-12-30');
$date->add(new DateInterval('Y30'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

For PHP 5.2

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-12-30');
$date->modify('+30 year');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: It's not a bug that makes the limit. It's the maximum number a 32 bit computer can handle. I can agree that it's a defect but not a bug.